# Is it possible to run C++ code inside an extern "C" block?

Tags: c++, c, interop

For example

```cpp
class demo {
public:
    static void printDemo(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Hi there" << std::endl;
    }
};

extern "C"{

void myInterrupt(void)
{
    demo::printDemo();
} 

}
```

Normally the `extern "C"` is for maintaining C-style linkage, so the declaration of `myInterrupt` matches the one in the interrupt vector declared in another file like `startup.S`, and the address of this function effectively gets installed in the vector.

But, does calling additional C++ functions inside of this block affect it?

Comment: `extern "C"` is really for declarations only. Code inside functions is not affected.

Comment: It is fine, the basic reason this syntax exists.

Comment: @HansPassant Or half of the reason, maybe. The syntax allows both declaring things that are defined in C, and defining things that can be declared in C.

Comment: There are, of course, restrictions on what an interrupt callback does - but that is true regardless of programming language.

Comment: `external “C”` is about names. It does not mean “compile this code as C”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to run C++ code inside an extern “C” block?

Yes.

The function has C interface in the sense that it can be called from a C program. But the implementation can contain C++ code.

> But does calling additional c++ functions inside this block affects it?

No.